# git pushしてしまった後にコミットのAuthorを変更する方法は？

Tags: git

## 概要

会社のGitHubに個人のGitHub名でPushしてしまったため、その名義を変更したい。

## 状況

会社のBitbucketに個人のGitHubアカウント名義のAuthorでPuthし、プルリクを開けてしまいました。
（1）`git commit --allow-empty -m "WIP"`で空コミット＆Push
（2）プルリクOpen
（3）しばらく作業し、コミット＆Push
（4）差分確認のためにプルリクのページを確認
（5）＼(^o^)／ｵﾜﾀ
な状態です。
※（2）で気づけとか言わないで…いつも使ってる名義なので違和感なかったの

## やってみたこと

以下サイトの記事通りに、

[GitのCommitユーザを修正する方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/y10exxx/items/dcea0e39788d649ca8ba)

```
 git filter-branch -f --env-filter \
  "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='new'; \
   GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='new@example.com'; \
   GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='new'; \
   GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='new@example.com';" \
  HEAD
```

を実行してみると、全コミットを書き換えようとしているように見えて、慌ててCtrl+C。
SourceTreeを確認したところ、書き換わっていないようで今の所ホッとしています。

しかし、この状況の打破にはならず困っています。

## 質問

特定のCommitのAuthorを変更するにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？
幸いにもCommitは4つほどなのでCommitID指定で書き換えも出来ます。
ご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけましと幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問内容に直接は関わらないのかもしれませんが、GitHubなのかBitBucketなのかが曖昧です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参照されているページの [補足](https://qiita.com/y10exxx/items/dcea0e39788d649ca8ba#%E8%A3%9C%E8%B6%B3)節、あるいは[GitHubヘルプ: 作者情報の変更](https://help.github.com/ja/github/using-git/changing-author-info)にも同じ主旨の内容が書かれていますが、それらは committerのemailで書き換えるコミットを絞り込んでいます:

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '

OLD_EMAIL="your-old-email@example.com"
CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

上記のコードでは `OLD_EMAIL` に書き換え対象のcommitのcommitter emailを設定するわけですが、ここに"個人のGitHubアカウント"のemailを設定することで所望の動作になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます！うまくいきました＞＜